# Sorting and Flagging the data

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, alteryx

I have a huge dataset lies in Amazon Redshift server and i need to do some sorting and flagging to the dataset (attached sample dataset for reference). Two tasks I need to achieve:

1. I need to sort the data by `S_Number` and `days_difference` in Ascending order
2. Flagging - Need to create a new column called `flag` and it should do the following steps:

   - If my row 1: `S_Number = row -1: S_Number then row -1: Flag +1 else 1`.

I am using Alteryx for pulling the data, but still I use SQL query for achieving the task. Any help would be really helpful.

I have given the links to the sample input file as well as expected output. Let me know my question is not clear.

[Sample_Input_File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfbkn3pzvfjsgrl/Sample_Input_Data_Stackoverflow.csv?dl=0)

[Expected_Output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fr7fuxmp22mpm67/Expected_Output_Stackoverflow.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems are you experiencing? Please simplify things by showing a few lines of input data and the output you would expect from them. Your supplied files don't seem to match. For example, the output file has an s_number of `5001181943B2`, but that isn't present in the input file. Also, please try to explain the `flag` a bit better. Feel free to Edit your question to provide this information.

Comment: If you're pulling the data with Alteryx anyway, then sorting in Alteryx is trivial, and a MuliRow Formula can assign your new flag column using almost the exact syntax you describe, although you could just group by S_Number and always set flag to row-1:flag + 1. That might start at 0 instead of 1, but is pretty easy.

Comment: Hi JohnRotenstein and johnjps111 - thanks for the reply. Due to characters constraint and not able to personally ping you guys for thanking and explain the scenarios. i have replied to your questions in a notepad and have uploaded the same. Please have a look at it. But i think Javier Ramirez has answered the question. 


John Rotenstein - https://www.dropbox.com/s/xd21vgrdmnvfyw4/Reply_to_John_Rotenstein.txt?dl=0

Johnjps111: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bxl959tmej4mvn/Reply_to_Johnjps111.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood properly, you want to sort the results and add the position of each row grouped by `S_Number`. If so, that is called a **"window function"** in SQL and in Redshift, and you can get results like the ones you shared with the query below. Please note I didn't run the query so it might have a small syntax error (hopefully not).

```
SELECT timestamp, S_Number, days_difference, ROW_NUMBER () OVER
(PARTITION BY S_Number ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS Flag
FROM your_table
ORDER BY S_Number ASC, timestamp ASC
```

Comment: Hi @Javier Ramirez thanks for the reply and yes this is what i was looking for. Still i need to validate it. But it does what i asked for. Thanks again